# Meaning of boundary condition for steady current density?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, boundary-conditions

Although I understand the derivation of boundary condition in case of steady electric current but I did not understand, that the electric field which is in direction of $J$ current density that is applied between two conducting medium so that if we analyse this electric field we should get that both tangent and normal component bet two medium is the same not only tangent component and the value of $J$ change due to different value of conductivity bet medium while the direction should still the same.

[image]

ok my question what if the field like i draw why the direction of current change although the same source should make the current,electric field in both conductors in the same direction [image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly clear what your question is. Your two equations have two distinct sources:

- The normal components must be equal, $J_{1n}=J_{2n}$, because otherwise there would be an accumulation of charge into the surface, which cannot be sustained in the steady state. This is because, for a normal from 1 into 2, the flow of charge that exits medium 1 in a small area $dA$ is $J_{1n}dA$ and the charge entering medium 2 is  $J_{2n}dA$.
- The tangential components on the other hand, can be different, because charge is just flowing past the boundary at different speeds. On the other hand, the electric field's tangential components must be continuous across the boundary, because otherwise there would be a nonzero circulation in the loop in your image. In a metal where Ohm's law holds, the current density is proportional to electric field,
  $$\mathbf{J}=\sigma \mathbf{E}$$
  and therefore the current density's tangential components will not in general be constant across the boundary.

This actually makes a lot of sense physically. Consider the following situation: two conductors of (smallish) conductivities $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are "sandwiched" between conducting plates with an applied voltage:

[image]

Here you'd expect the current to be vertical, and greater in the material with greater conductivity. Thus the current density components tangential to the separating surface will *not* be equal.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain the interface properties of the electric field to help you understand why this is so.
First, it is well known for conductors that the electric field inside a conductor must be zero. If it were not, it would cause current to flow, and propagation of current involves the dissipation of energy, and this cannot occur without any external sources of energy. Hence, it follows that any charges in the conductor must be located on its surface.

Since the mean magnetic field is assumed to be zero, the derivative ${\partial H}/{\partial t} = 0$, and we find that the static electric field in the vacuum satisfies the equations $\nabla \bullet   E = 0$ and $\nabla \times E = 0$.

The boundary conditions on the field $E$ at the surface of the conductor follow from the equation  $\nabla \times E = 0$, and is both valid outside and inside the body. Take the z-axis in the direction of the normal $n$ to the surface at some point in the conductor. If the surface is homogeneous, the derivatives,  ${\partial E_z}/{\partial x}$ and  ${\partial E_z}/{\partial y}$  along the surface remain finite even tough $E_z$ may be quite large.

Hence, since $\nabla_x \times E = \partial E_z/\partial y - \partial E_y/\partial z = 0$, we find that $\partial E_y/\partial z$ is finite. This means that $E_y$ is continuous at the surface since a discontinuity in $E_y$ would mean an infinity of the derivative $\partial E_y/\partial z$. The same applies to $E_x$ and since $E=)0$ inside the conductor, we reach the conclusion that the tangential components of the electric field at the surface must be zero $$E_t= 0$$

For the case of two conductors under static ﬁeld conditions (i.e. $∂E/∂t= 0$ and $∂B/∂t= 0$, there can be no charge build up at the interface and hence $$J_{n1} =J_{n2}$$

Comment: In your last paragraph, does it mean that if the interface is not between two conductors but between two perfect insulators instead,  a discontinuity in the normal components of the current density might exist? Another related question is that, since even a good insulator still conducts current slightly, in reality, the normal components of the current density will always be continuous, correct?